# JavaScript string output font color

Tags: javascript, string, fonts

I am relatively new to the JavaScript coding language and it feels much different from webscripts like html and css. 
So, what I am trying to do is to change font color and background color of javascript outputs. What I have are the following two lines

```
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML += "Print Primary<br/>";
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML += "Print Secondary<br/>";
```

I have tried

```
document.getElementById("ID.fontcolor("red")).innerHTML += "Print Primary"; 
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML += set.fontcolor("red") += "Print Secondary";
```

Also, how would you change the background color?

p.s, the same ID is being looped, but i want it to be color red when printing Primary and color yellow when printing Secondary and NOT change the previous printed elements color

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information

Comment: See -> **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style** you have most of it in `style`, i.e `document.getElementById("ID").style.color = 'red';` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of a text inside an element, you can reach it by editing the style properties of the element. Like this:

```
document.getElementById("idElement").style.color = "#FF0000"; //Or you can just put "red". Works with some colors.
```

The way you do it with native DOM elements is a bit different when using jQuery, for example.
Here is a reference about how you can change the color of DOM elements: [W3Schools Style color property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp)

EDIT:

If you need to change the color of more than one element with this JS code, then you need to get the DOM elements by its class. By definition, IDs must be unique when using pure Javascript to get the elements. Then, you cannot get a list of elements by ID. 
In this case, you can use the "class" attribute to get the list of elements that will have the color changed.

Take a look:

```
<span class="spanColor">text 1</span>
<span class="spanColor">text 2</span>
<span class="spanColor">text 3</span>
<span class="spanColor">text 4</span>
<span class="spanColor">text 5</span>
<script>
    var objs = document.getElementsByClassName("spanColor");

    for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2)
        {
            objs[i].style.color = "#FF0000"; // Red
        }
        else
        {
            objs[i].style.color = "#EAFF00"; // Yellow
        }
    }

</script>
```

With this change, you can alternate between yellow and red colors.

Comment: Hi, this changes the color of every element that have already been printed. Is there a way to not change the previous color? For example, first is yellow (should be color yellow), next is red ( color red), next is yellow (should be color yellow), and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can try looping through each element you have, and setting it to the color of the text inside the element, like so:

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("color");

for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
{
    var text = els[i].innerHTML;
    els[i].style.color = text;
}
```

```html
<div class="color">Red</div>
<div class="color">Yellow</div>
```